# Boot problem Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, drivers, grub2, nvidia

I am having trouble installing ubuntu 16.06 on my desktop, I tried everything I found for people with similar problems and nothing worked.

Hardware info:

CPU AMD Ryzen 2200g

GPU nvidia gtx 970

mother board Asus rog strix b350f gaming (bios updated)

ram memory 8 gb 2400Hz kingspec - 4gb hyperfury 2133Hz

Without the gpu it gives some error messages but is able to install and works properly with nomodeset, so It's something to do with the gpu and acpi. I don't think it's nvidia drivers, because after installing without the  gpu and installing the drivers it didint boot as well.

But with gpu it can only boot with acpi=off and after some boots it wont boot anymore, i cannot complete the installation most of the time if i use gpu and acpi=off.

I really need to solve the acpi=off with gpu, because while in acpi=off the system works only with a single core.

Also I tried using ubuntu boot repair and it didin't work out, here's some information from the boot repair on this link: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/XpQkhPHMSb/

And here is what i think is the critical error, i didint know how to record the boot log so I made a video of the boot trying to install ubuntu from USB image with gpu and nomoset.
https://youtu.be/R7YwsTxgWTk

Hope someone can help, thanks

---

Comment: Install drivers, disable Secure Boot and remove nomodeset.

Comment: Hey thanks for reply, I did just that and funny thing is: after fresh install and then installing the drivers it boots correctly with gpu only once, then all boots get stuck in a purple textless screen after grub